# Usage of the word "demise"

Tags: nouns, word-usage

Is it appropriate to use *demise* in the following sentence:

> it is with deep sympathy that we announce the sad **demise** of ...

It sounds archaic and I was not sure whether it was used correctly. How is *demise* usually used?

Comment: I wouldn't use "demise". I'd say "It is with great sadness that we announce the death of So&So and express our deepest sympathy to So&So's SO". People are sad, not deaths.

Comment: For a person (or beloved pet) don't use "demise".  But go ahead and use "demise" for an organization.  *We announce the demise of Hostess Foods.*  Or maybe even some despised animals or plants.  *We announce the demise of the wasps under your porch.*

Comment: In case this is borne from your experience, my sympathies for your loss.

Comment: @GEdgar Opinion, I should think?

Comment: All these comments and answers are merely opinions because usage is always a question of style and personal preference.

Comment: This is entirely an opinion, for the record...while "demise" may be used correctly in your example, it is a less than elegant way to word a death announcement where friends and acquaintances of the deceased are just learning of the death.  Bill Franke's suggestion is much more thoughtfully worded.  Leave "demise" for prose and news articles.

Answer (score 8):

It is entirely appropriate to use *demise* in that sentence. Statements of sympathy and condolence are normally of a rather solemn and formal nature, and the higher register is entirely suitable to the occasion. *Demise* is also a less direct term than *death*: the use of euphemism, however minor, softens the bald statement of what may be to some a tragic passing.

Answer (score 2):

The use of *demise* is correct in the given context. Just as one might say '*passing away*'.

It is not archaic but formal and somewhat euphemistic. In an obituary announcement, *demise* is used rather than *death* — so as not to hurt sentiments.

> [demise](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/demise) noun [in singular] <sub>(OxfordDictionaries)</sub>
>   **1** a person’s death: *Mr Grisenthwaite’s tragic demise*
>   the end or failure of an enterprise or institution: *the demise of industry*

Wikipedia notes that it is a euphemism

> Through euphemism, "(a person's) [demise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demise)" is often used as a stilted term for a person's death.

1911 Encyclopædia Britannica records:

> "[Demise](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/1911_Encyclop%C3%A6dia_Britannica/Demise)" is thus often used loosely for death or decease.

Note the word *often* in both the later references.

"[YourTribute](http://resources.yourtribute.com/?s=demise)"
*We can’t imagine the grief you must be suffering from his demise.*
*I am completely shocked at the sudden demise of your brother. Please accept my sincere condolence.*
*Coping with the emotional turmoil after the demise of a family member or friend is a heart wrenching experience.*

Comment: +1 for mention of "passing away", better choice, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

*Demise* can be used to describe the death of a person (perhaps especially in the case of a famous yet not-necessarily-beloved person, or in a tragic and untimely death), or to the crumbling downfall of an institution. I believe the latter usage is more common in modern writing, but I couldn't say that for sure (although the usages listed on the [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/demise) page would seem to back me up).

That said, I don't know if I'd go so far as to call your example usage *archaic*. It's certainly within the scope of the [dictionary's definition](http://www.onelook.com/?w=demise&ls=a), and it's not hard to find such usages in a [Google book search](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22his%20demise%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1980,cd_max:2005&lr=lang_en):

> The deathblow had occurred as he rolled up the front of the truck and bounced, then met his demise on the upturned tailgate of the pickup truck. (from *Angel of Death – Downfall*, by H. Edward Newton, 2004)

Answer (score 0):

My father used the term to refer to my mother’s death in a letter : « her impending demise », and it struck me like a bolt of lightning, so cold, so detached, so formal. Perhaps because English was his second language and he wanted to show off that he knew some fancy words. But the effect was very hurtful. I would strongly advise anyone not to use the term if they wish to convey warm, sincere condolences.

Comment: Pascale, I'm sorry about your loss and the way the word "demise" impacted on you. However, our site is looking for *authoritative* answers. Occasionally, a contributor might use their own experience as a form of authority – for example, in confirming unusual usage or pronunciation in their locality – but in cases such as yours, personal experience is **not** authoritative and instead is *subjective opinion*. "Demise" IS an appropriate usage when the register is formal, but it's inappropriate when conveying – as you say – "warm, sincere condolences". *Context is everything.*